# Remove ascii characters in a string python

Tags: python, string, escaping

I want to delete special characters in the string. However, I was not successful. can you help me?

It shows two "" each, but when you print it becomes only "". Why could it be?.

Data Update:

```
data = [{
            "data": "0\\x1e\\x82*.extractdomain.com\\x82\\x0ctest.extractdomain.com",
            "name": "subjectAltName"
        }]

re.sub("[^\x20-\x7E]", "", data["data"])
```

Comment: does `\x` is a special character ?

Comment: For example, I want to delete \ x82 and \ x16

Comment: Your string contains literal backslash characters. It does not contain any "special" (non-ascii) characters. (I am guessing a bit what you mean by "special", of course.)

Comment: By special do you mean a specific set of letters you want to remove, or do you mean symbols such as &@/% etc?

Comment: Please add a few sample inputs and expected outputs. I should make it clear enough

Comment: Maybe pure python would be best here: `''.join(x for x in text if 20 <= ord(x) <= 127)`

Comment: @CoryNezin And you will get exactly the original string. It does not contain any characters outside of that range. The escaped backslashes result in literal backslashes, not the start of another escape sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
clean_text = ' '.join(re.findall(r"[^\W]+", text))
```

EDIT:
or this.

```
custom_translation = {130: None, 22: None}
print(text.translate(custom_translation))
```

The post has been edited "text changed" and this solution isn't working anymore.
Old text was

```
text = '0:\x82 test test test\x82\x16testtesttest'
```

Newer Solution:

```
custom_translation = {22: None, 49: None, 50: None, 54: None, 56: None, 92: None, 120: None}
print(text.translate(custom_translation))
```

Comment: This works well, but it can't be edited to encompass specific characters – only a generic set of non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: I have updated my question now. It shows two "\" each, but when you print it becomes only "\". Why could it be?

Comment: @monsieuralfonse64 if you tried to remove something like `\x82` it won't work because re will recognize it as a special character, that's why the best solution would be using `\W`.

Comment: @aden70752 How is it not working?, i just tried it before a second and it worked perfectly, what's the ouput for you?

Comment: @aden70752 have a look at escaping in python strings vs regular expressions: [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague). It is quite complicated involving lots of backslashes hence why " raw"strings are used: `r"string"`. Characters such as newlines in these strings are ignored

Answer (score 1):

```
txt = "0:\\x82 test test test\\x82\\x16testtesttest"
x = re.sub("\\\\(?:x16|x82)", "", txt)
```

As a generalization of such characters:

```
x = re.sub("\\\\(?:x\w\w)", "", txt)
```

Output:

```
0: test test testtesttesttest
```

Good to know:

In short, to match a literal backslash, one has to write '\\' as the RE string, because the regular expression must be \, and each backslash must be expressed as \ inside a regular Python string literal. In REs that feature backslashes repeatedly, this leads to lots of repeated backslashes and makes the resulting strings difficult to understand.

Another way is to use Python’s raw string notation for regular expressions; backslashes are not handled in any special way in a string literal prefixed with 'r', so r"\n" is a two-character string containing '' and 'n', while "\n" is a one-character string containing a newline. Regular expressions will often be written in Python code using this raw string notation.

For more examples - [Backslash Plague](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#:%7E:text=In%20short%2C%20to%20match%20a,a%20regular%20Python%20string%20literal.)

Comment: I think the main problem is that the ascii characters don't look right. This regex works but \\n \\t doesn't work. I can't understand why the Ascii characters are perceived as if they have two "\"?

Comment: May be if you treat it as raw string then it will solve your problem. I have added the explanation and a link where you can see a clear explanation of how \ works in python

Comment: @aden70752 python uses backslashes for special characters in string literals. So does re. So you need to escape backslashed characters which you want re to interpret with another backslash, because python will then ignore it. Or you could use a raw string.

Answer (score 0):

the error is in the declaration of `text`, you double escape the `\`, so you are writing a plain `\` instead of escaping an hexadecimal char

```
text = '0:\x82 test test test\x82\x16testtesttest'

print(re.sub("[^\x20-\x7E]", "", text))
```

prints:
`0: test test testtesttesttest`

Comment: what did you try ? as I said it works (on py2 & py3)

Comment: I think the main problem is that the ascii characters don't look right. This regex works.  I can't understand why the Ascii characters are perceived as if they have two "\"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
import re


def delete_punc(s):

  s1 = s.split()

  match_pattern1 = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]', (str(s1[0])))
  match_pattern2 = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]', (str(s1[1])))



  listToStr1 = ''.join([str(elem) for elem in match_pattern1])
  listToStr2 = ''.join([str(elem) for elem in match_pattern2])

  return listToStr1 + ' ' + listToStr2

print(delete_punc("He3l?/l!o W{o'r[l9\d)"))
```

output

```
Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the string contains `\x` escapes which have themselves been escaped, leading to the doubled backslashes.  Perhaps you received the data like this, or perhaps some earlier processing has corrupted the data.  The doubled backslashes can be removed by encoding the string as bytes and then decoding with the unicode-escape codec.  After this, your regex will work.

```python
>>> s = "0\\x1e\\x82*.extractdomain.com\\x82\\x0ctest.extractdomain.com"
>>> fixed = s.encode('latin-1').decode('unicode-escape')
>>> fixed
'0\x1e\x82*.extractdomain.com\x82\x0ctest.extractdomain.com'
>>> re.sub("[^\x20-\x7E]", "", fixed)
'0*.extractdomain.comtest.extractdomain.com'
```